# JSON foreach error to get name

Tags: php, json, foreach

I´ve got the following errormessage:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /var/www/createRecipeIng.php on line 60
```

Don´t know how to handle that, never had before.

Here´s the code:

```
$ings =  array();
$ings = json_decode($incr_arr, true);
print_r($ings);
$reid = 5;

foreach ($ings['Data']['Recipes']['Recipe_' . $reid] as key => $shIng){
    echo $shIng['NAME'];
}
```

Line 60 is the line with the foreach loop. I know that the error must be there because the values of $ings are correct.

How can I manage this?

Comment: You missed a `$` sign from the front of `key` (variable declaration)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the element key just like any other variable.

You declared `key` when it should be `$key`.

Check the [PHP manual](http://se.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for future reference.

Code fix

```
foreach ($ings['Data']['Recipes']['Recipe_' . $reid] as $key => $shIng){
    echo $shIng['NAME'];
}
```